# Download file using @post in Rest service in java

Tags: java, rest

Hi I have a requirement to download a pdf file after method execution.
i write code like below

```
 private static final String FILE_PATH = "d:\\Test2.zip";
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile() {
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=newfile.zip");
    return response.build();

}
```

But as I have to send huge data in request I want to use @POST instead of @GET signature.How to do that please help

Comment: REST operations shloud distinct "read state" -> GET, change state -> POST

Comment: Regarding your question: by changing `@GET` to `@POST`.

Comment: I didn't get you.If i just change to post it's giving raw data.

Comment: Explain clearly what you want to achieve, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. I don't undrstand what you mean by "it's giving raw data".

Comment: Hi @JBNizet
I am unable to get the zip file ,instead of it's opening browser with raw data unreadable format

Comment: Why not just return a String containing a link to your pdf file (or is it a zip file). Clicking the link will download the file. Or redirect to your file inside your REST method.